# Django materialized view migration problem on update

Tags: python, django, materialized-views

We are building a library in Django (v4.0) with Postgres (v13). This library is going to be the core for our company, so we have to be careful with the migrations. The problem is with Django migrations when we update the base table for any materialized view.

1. Models:

- Base

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "customer"
```

- Materialized View

```py
class CustomerDetailView(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "customer_detail_view"
```

2. Migrations:

- "0001_initial.py" Created by Django

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomerDetailView',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('external_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'customer_detail_view',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Customer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('external_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True, unique=True))
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'customer',
            },
        ),
```

- "0002_customer_detail_view.py" Created manually

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("customers", "0001_initial"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            """
            DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS customer_detail_view;
            CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW customer_detail_view AS
            SELECT
                cus.id,
                cus.external_id,
            FROM
                customer cus;
            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_detail_view_pk ON customer_detail_view(external_id);
            """,
            "DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW customer_detail_view"
        )
    ]
```

- "0003_alter_customer_external_id.py" Created by Django after a dummy modification on the base table

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('customers', '0002_customer_detail_view'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='customer',
            name='external_id',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=60, null=True, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

3. The error

- Occurs when we do `python manage.py migrate`

```bash
Running migrations:
  Applying customers.0003_alter_customer_external_id...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on materialized view customer_detail_view depends on column "external_id"
```

We think the problem is related to the "0001_initial.py" migration where Django (even though the materialized view is a table with `managed=False`) creates a migration and then when the base is updated it is not possible to create a migration for the materialized view.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to alter field used in the materialized view. This will always fail. You have to drop `customer_detail_view` before you can alter fields in the related `customer` table. Personally, I never include materialized views in migrations because of problems like this one. Move them out of migrations (your 2nd migration) and into management command with the option to drop and (re)create them when needed.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution we removed the materialized views from the migrations and we overload the django command "migrate" to drop the materialized views before the execution of the command and after that we recreate and fill the materialized views.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not support materialized view migrations by the default. That's why you should write migrations manually. You are not able to change model `Customer` with field `external_id` (in case the materialized view is created from `Customer` model and the field `external_id`) until you delete the materialized view. You can create custom migration to delete materialized view and apply model changes, then create again your materialized views. But there is easy solution to manage it:

You can integrate your materialized views to the Django with this library [django-materialized-view](https://github.com/muehlemann-popp/django-materialized-view)

All that you need:

1. Get view_definitions (If you don't now query of materialized views):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.views
WHERE table_schema = 'information_schema'
AND table_name = 'views';
```

2. Use [django-materialized-view](https://github.com/muehlemann-popp/django-materialized-view) according to the description
3. Enjoy with materialized views in your project.